# Vue3 Dockerized loseing environment variables after refreshing page

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, vuejs3, production

The issue: I'm getting undefined environment variables when I'm reloading the page.

My Stack:
I'm developing a WebApp with the following architecture:

- Client: Vue3
- Api: Express Nodejs

I'm using a 2 docker-compose files:

- docker-compose.yml for development;
- docker-compose-production.yml for production;

The behaviour (getting undefined env variables) is happening in the production mode.

**My docker-compose-production file:**

```
version: "3"

services:

  api:
    build:
      context: ./api
    container_name: api
    ports: 
      - "3001:3001"
    environment:
      API_PORT: "3001"
    restart: always

  client:
    build:
      context: ./client
    container_name: client
    ports: 
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      VUE_APP_BACKEND_HOST: localhost
      VUE_APP_BACKEND_PORT: "3001"
    restart: always
```

Client Dockerfile:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 node:13-slim as build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM --platform=linux/amd64 nginx:alpine
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist /usr/src/app
COPY entrypoint.sh generate-env-prod.sh /
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "/entrypoint.sh"]
```

To load my env variables, here is my methodology:

I created an "entrypoint.sh" script

```
sh ./generate-env-prod.sh > /usr/src/app/env.js
nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

The 'generate-env-prod.sh' script, to store env variables in the window.* :

```
cat <<EOF
window.VUE_APP_BACKEND_HOST="${VUE_APP_BACKEND_HOST}"
window.VUE_APP_BACKEND_PORT="${VUE_APP_BACKEND_PORT}"
EOF
```

In the public directory, I created an empty env.js file to store the environment variables.

In the index.html file, I added the following script inside the  section to load the environment variables in the Client app:

```
<script src="env.js"></script>
```

In my services, I created the following config.service.js file, allowing to load the appropriate environment variable either in production or development modes:

```
export default new class ConfigService {

    get(key) {
        console.log('window[key] : ', window[key])
        return this.isProduction() ? window[key] : process.env[key]
    }

    getEnvName() {
        console.log('process.env.NODE_ENV : ', process.env.NODE_ENV)
        return process.env.NODE_ENV
    }

    isProduction() {
        return this.getEnvName() === "production"
    }
}
```

My Vue main.js file:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import './assets/tailwind.css'

createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app')
```

My App.vue file:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <NavBar />
    <router-view/>
  </div>
  
</template>

<script>
import NavBar from './components/NavBar.vue'
export default {
  components: { NavBar },
}
</script>
```

Now, when I run `docker-compose -f docker-compose-production.yml up --build` (the production mode), I'm having the required environment variables when I'm on the Home page. If I'm navigating to another page, it's still have the loaded env variables.

BUT, if I'm reloading the page, I'm getting all my window.* variables undefined, while the env.js file is still having the value.

I hope I gave enough details about my issue. Do you have an idea on how I should proceed to get my env variables everywhere, even if I reload the page?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to load the `env.js` using absolute URL instead of relative ? `<script src="/env.js"></script>`

Comment: It works ! Thanks a lot ! You saved me hours of search...

Comment: Great. Next time save yourself even more time by using browser DevTools instead of posting question on internet. The fact that `env.js` is not loading on refresh (and the URL browser is trying to use to load it) would be pretty clear from the Network tab

Comment: You are right! Thank you for the tip! (I'm beginner, I'm learning :-D)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comment, I simply added absolute path instead of relative one, and everything worked perfectly.

Thus, in `public/index.html`, I had:

```
<script src="env.js"></script>
```

Changed into

```
<script src="/env.js"></script>
```